# Keep getting "error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout' and error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved

Tags: c++, cout, endl

I am writing a sorting program using a host of different functions as y'all can see from
    my declarations. However, I keep getting these same errors when I try to compile and run my program
    they are as follows:

1. `error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'; did you mean 'count'?`

   `cout << "Hello from main" << endl;`
2. `error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did
   you mean to call it?`

   `cout << "Hello from main" << endl;`
3. `error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'; did you mean 'end'?`
   `cout << "Hello from main" << endl;`

I'm not really sure why I am getting these errors....I thought I included everything I needed to 
in order to use "cout" and "endl" when I included using namespace std...
I have a feeling it has something to do with all my function declarations, but that's just a hunch
Any help that y'all can give would be greatly appreciated!!!!!

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <typename Comparable>
void insertionSort(vector<Comparable> & a);

template <typename Comparable>
void heapsort(vector<Comparable> & a);

template <typename Comparable>
void percDown(vector<Comparable> & a, int i, int n);

template <typename Comparable>
void mergeSort(vector<Comparable> & a, vector<Comparable> & tmpArray, int left, int right);

template <typename Comparable>
void mergeSort(vector<Comparable> & a);

template <typename Comparable>
void merge(vector<Comparable> & a, vector<Comparable> & tmpArray, int leftPos, int rightPos, int rightEnd);

template <typename Comparable>
void quicksort(vector<Comparable> & a);

template <typename Comparable>
const Comparable & median3(vector<Comparable> & a, int left, int right);

template <typename Comparable>
void quicksort(vector<Comparable> & a, int left, int right);


int main()
{
    vector<int> myVector;
    cout << "Hello from main" << endl; ///This is where the error is//////
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 11):

You have to `#include <iostream>`. It is where `std::cout` is declared.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to add the proper library:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should add `#include <iostream>` in the beginning of your program

Answer (score 2):

Check for these lines in the beginning of your c++ program.

`#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;`